# element click intercepted / Other element would receive the click [Selenum Python & Instagram :)]

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I need help. I am trying to click an element in Selenium Python, but I get the following message:

selenium.common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted: Element is not clickable at point (318, 450). Other element would receive the click:

```
                driver.find_element_by_xpath('(//img[@decoding="auto"])[1]').click()
```

This is the XPath I created. Its the only node. The element is visible, I don't see any other element that can receive that click. I am torturing myself for a while now. Any help is appreciated.  The link from where I try to click that element https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/bass/

EDIT: Thanks to pcalkins, I managed to find a workaround. here is the working code:

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 100, poll_frequency=1)
            pic = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '(//img)[2]')))
            ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(pic).click().perform()
```

Comment: include the part of the exception that lists the element that would receive the click.  (In general the event handler would be on an <a>, tag instead of the <img> tag, so confirm that the <img> has an event handler.)  Seems like you're clicking on the wrong item.

Comment: @pcalkins thanks! You were right, I was clicking at the wrong element + I had to use action chains 

I will edit the question :) thanks again